# Include one array inside another complex array using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following arrays:

```
array = [ [link_text1, link1],[link_text2, link2], ... ]
array = [ [views1],[views2], ... ]
```

How can I can combine them, so I get this array:

```
[ [link_text1, link1, views1], [link_text2, link2, views2], ... ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a cartesian product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as robinst, but a little shorter

```
a1 = [ ["link_text1", "link1"],["link_text2", "link2"] ]
a2 = [ ["views1"],["views2"] ]
a1.zip(a2).map(&:flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of zip and flatten:

```
a1 = [ ["link_text1", "link1"],["link_text2", "link2"] ]
a2 = [ ["views1"],["views2"] ]
zipped = a1.zip(a2)
array_final = zipped.collect { |a| a.flatten }
#=> [["link_text1", "link1", "views1"], ["link_text2", "link2", "views2"]]
```